# Mutual benefits of coding theory and the reconstruction conjecture

Tags: graph-theory, coding-theory

Let $G_n$ denotes all graphs with $n$ nodes. For any graph $G$ in $G_n$, the adjacency matrix $A(G)$ can be viewed as a codeword of length $n^2$. Also, the codes arises from $G_n$ is a linear binary code.

Now, I want to see the RC conjecture as a coding problem. The Reconstruction conjecture (RC): we can reconstruct any $n$-vertex graph $G$ from the collection of all $(n−1)$-vertex graphs obtained by deleting one vertex of $G$ (together with all edges involving that vertex)

Let we have a code word (corresponding to the graph $G$ with $n$ vertices) and we send it in the channel. The channel is so wild and deletes and permutes some bits such that we receive a word of length $(n-1)^2$ (corresponding to the induced vertex deleted subgraph of the graph $G$) in the receiver. In our channel, we can request $n$-times for sending the original codeword, and all time we receive a word corresponding to the vertex deleted induced subgraph of the graph $G$ (all deck).

By this terminology, we have a decoding problem for Burst error channel with allowed request repetition.

**My question is**: *Does it show that the RC problem is as hard as decoding problem?*

One interesting advantage for this correspondence is in coding theory. By Alon's theorem, this type of coding has easy decoding with at most three time request.

Comment: you might as well tell us what the RC conjecture is.

Comment: @kodlu, I believe it's the conjecture that you can reconstruct any $n$-vertex graph $G$ from the collection of all $n-1$-vertex graphs obtained by deleting one vertex of $G$ (together with all edges involving that vertex); I agree that OP should include this in the body of the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for your comment. I will add your comment in the body of the question.